# Idiomatic usage of “müssen”

Tags: modal-verb, idiomaticity, modal-particle, spoken-language

I’m watching “Deutschland 83”, and one of the characters said “Du musst geh nach Berlin”, which confused me because I had always learned that modal verbs always kicked the second verb to the end of the sentence as “Du musst nach Berlin gehen”.

I was hoping someone could explain this exception; I expect that it has do do with the imperative/ordering nature of the sentence.

Comment: “Du musst geh nach Berlin” is not correct. Maybe they said “Du musst gehen, nach Berlin”.

Comment: Okay, i'll go back and watch it again. Thanks

Comment: Or perhaps it was "Du musst, geh nach Berlin" (=You have to, go to Berlin).

Comment: I'd also think that the colloquial version of the sentence *du musst nach Berlin gehen* would be *du musst nach Berlin*, simply leaving out *gehen* since *nach* implies it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase is not correct. The correct meaning would be — as you said — “Du musst nach Berlin gehen.”

The mentioned variant with a comma, as in “Du musst gehen, nach Berlin”, could technically be used, but it’s rare. Here you would probably say “Du musst nach Berlin gehen” as well, which is much simpler in its construction and more commonly used.

However, given that it was supposed to mean indeed “Du musst gehen, nach Berlin”, then the first part of the sentence would indicate that the person has to go, while after the comma in an addition, *German Nebensatz* the location is added, which might have been forgotton in the first place and is hastily added now.

Comment: Actually, _Du musst gehen, nach Berlin_ is perfectly standard **spoken** German. It’s only unusual (= highly marked) in written German.

Comment: @Crissov: I don't think I would ever use the sentence like this deliberately even in spoken German, unless - as BenjB pointed out - I forgot to mention the "place" and wanted to add it without starting a new sentence. But I do not think I would ever "plan" to add the "place"-information this way.

Comment: @Gerhard The amount and depth of “planning“ is probably the most important reason for differences in the literal and oral registers of languages.

Comment: What do you mean by a *German Nebensatz*? It implies something inherently German and if I had to guess, you are using it in a derogative way. Please elaborate.

Comment: At least in south Germany, it was perfectly normally to put prepositional phrases at the end of the sentence. In fact, I was specifically told this by my host family, because I sounded too formal. Granted, putting prepositional phrases at the end of a sentence is much more common in larger sentences, and in this specific case I'd pretty much always use the normal *du musst nach Berlin gehen*.